# Select contents of div javascript selects more text than needed

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script to select contents of selectable. But it selects more text than it should, in this case only URL should be selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/PcvRK/2/

```
function selectText() {
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById('selectable'));
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById('selectable'));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm using Chrome, didn't test in other browsers.

Comment: What does it select if not just URL? What gets selected?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik under jsfiddle all works fine, but within my wordpress dashboard it selects also texts immediately after it, http://holiday.ge/en/referral/?user=sandro
You currently referred: 10

Comment: Where on your page is this selection or how do I invoke selection? Do I have to click anything?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik you have to register, and it is under dashboard, sorry :(

Comment: This really helps... :) We can't really see what you've done then? And as you say **it works in JSFiddle**. So how do you expect us to help you then? Create some dummy registration then and provide username/password we can use. You don't expect us to register do you? Unless you're fishing here... In which case you'll quickly get *flagged*.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Well, I'm not fishing. I copied to jsfiddle thinking it was my js. But it works there. Problem is within wordpress. Should I copy whole html?

Comment: No. Either produce the problem in JSFiddle or provide dummy username/password combination with which we can get to your page and see the problem... I don't see any other way of helping you. The first thing that I would look at on that page would be to check whether that particular element has other things inside and not just the URL. Because other things get selected as well. If it doesn't, maybe it has defined pseudo elements on it whose content would likely get selected as well because they're part of the content.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik test_user 123456789. Just let me upload js version again. I removed it cause it wasn't working fine.

Comment: I've tried logging in but it seems I'm only able to log in using Google, FB or Yahoo? I thought you also allow signing up without any and that's where I wanted to have a test user and then use it to log in...